# How to make server wait until database connection is established? node/mongodb/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have two files: server.js and database.js

the code for server.js is the following:

```
const express = require('express');
var db = require('./database');

const app = express();
.
.
some get/post methods
app.listen(3000);
.
.
```

The code for database.js is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const db = mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://xxx:YYYYY@"+
    "cluster0.zrpqzwp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
        useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then((result) => console.log('connected to db'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

So I don't want app.listen(3000) until database connection is established. This can be done if it was all in one file by using .then( ... app.listen(3000)) but I dont want to do that. Is there any other way to do something similar with my current configuration?

Comment: "This can be done if it was all in one file by using .then(...).".  Q: Why does it have to be "one file"? It sounds like a promise is EXACTLY what you're looking for.  So what's preventing you from adding a function to database.js that that calls "connect()" and returns a promise???

Answer (score 0):

Rather than exporting `db` from `database.js` you should export `getDb` - a function that returns a DB.

```
module.exports = async function getDb() {
   return mongoose.connect(...)
}
```

Then in your `server.js` you can do

```
const getDb = require('./database.js')
...
getDb().then(() => app.listen(3000));
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. How would I make it so that everything else on server.js waits for getDb to be initialized? Or does the body of the code in NodeJS not execute until all of the require statements are done first?

Comment: If you were using ESM imports (rather than CJS require), you might be able to use top level await (depending on your node version). However, your best option is to put anything you want to happen after `getDb` into a function, and use promise chaining as in the answer